# I am sending data through form, it is not working

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have this delete function in my system but first I need the server needs to know which table he has to delete that is why I am sending a data when the user click the delete button into the server which is the ID of the data I want to delete..first I need to try and get that data being sent by the form but the problem is sending data is not working in my part I tried to echo out the ID just to see if I have a result but it works fine but when I send it to the server it doesn't print anything.. Here is my code where I fetch the scheduleID and the form

```
  if ($strand<>""){
                $query1 = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * from schedule  natural join instructor where day = 'm' and  schedule.strand= '$strand' and timeID ='$id' and grade = '$grade' and semester = '$semester'");
            }
            $row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($query1);
            $schedID = $row['scheduleID'];
            $id = $row1 ['scheduleID'];
            $count=mysqli_num_rows($query1);
            if ($count==0)//checking
                {
         //echo "<td></td>";


        }
        else
            {
            //print 
            echo "<div class='show'>";  
            echo "<ul>
                        <li class='options' style='display:inline'>
                            <span style='float:left;'><a href='sched_edit.php?id=$id1' class='edit' title='Edit'>Edit</a></span>
                                <span class='action'><a href='#' id='$id1' class='delete' title='Delete'>Remove</a></span>
                        </li>";
                        echo "<form class = 'delete' method = 'post' action ='../functions/delete.php'>";
                        echo "<li class='showme'>";
                        echo " <input type='hidden' name='delete' value='$id'>";
                        echo "<button type='submit' name='delete' class='btn btn-danger'>Display Schedule</button>";
                        echo $row1['subject'];
                        echo "</li>";
                        echo "<li class='$displayc'>$row1[strand]";
                        echo "<li class='$displaym'>$row1[fname], $row1[lname]</li>";                                           
                        echo "<li class='$displayr'>Room $row1[room]</li>";
                        echo "</form>";             
                        echo "</ul>";
                        echo "</div>";
                                        }   
            ?>
            </td>
```

I tried the hidden attribute in some of my forms and it work there but I don't know why it won't in this form, the $id is working also I tried echoing that inside in this page but the data sent is not printing in the server, here's my server

```
    <?php 
session_start();
include 'database.php';

 if (isset($_POST['delete'])){
        $ID = $_POST['delete'];
 }
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Try taking the `name="delete"` off of the button.

Comment: If you have 2 elements with the same name, PHP only keeps the last value.  I think that's how you're losing your ID value, because button doesn't have a value.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you have 2 form elements using the same `name` attribute, so PHP is only keeping the last value, which is not defined.

See both the `<input>` and the `<button>` have the same name! The button is last and has no value; that is what is being used by PHP.

```
<input type='hidden' name='delete' value='$id'>
<button type='submit' name='delete' class='btn btn-danger'>Display Schedule</button>
```

**So you can just remove the name from the button or change it to something other than `delete`** :-)

Comment: I already change the name of my input into rest and change my POST in the server but it doesn't give any results sir

Comment: what do you get if you do `var_dump($_POST)`?

Comment: Maybe you aren't setting the value of `$id`?  The code above does not show that you are actually setting it.... maybe try replacing `value='$id'` with `value=99` just to see if the 99 makes it through.

Comment: I tried it sir and it works :) Now I just need to think of a way to delete and redirect to the frontpage not in my server